# How to install packages without updating the existing ones

Tags: r, alteryx

I want to install R packages without updating the existing ones. for example, I am installing "dplyr", but it imports several others as given in the list below from the cran pdf. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf

```
Depends R (¿= 3.2.0)
Imports assertthat (¿= 0.2.0),
glue (¿= 1.3.0),
magrittr (¿= 1.5),
methods,
pkgconfig,
R6,
Rcpp (¿= 1.0.1),
rlang (¿= 0.4.0),
tibble (¿= 2.0.0),
tidyselect (¿= 0.2.5),
utils
```

I have tried `install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = F)` but it seems still install/updates the other packages.

What I want is a function (or a set of options) which checks if the other packages which are required already exists then don't install/update them, if the version is incompatible, then give warning. only install packages which do not exist already.

The reason I want to do it is, I plan to write R code in a software called "Alteryx", which comes with R and a lot of packages out of the box. But when I install new R packages in Alteryx, the updates to existing packages throws an error.

I read the documentation for `install.packages` which has an option for `libs_only` but its a little bit confusing to me. I am not sure if it does what i need.

Comment: To a first approximation, "you can't" as R thinks differently about this and always wants everything current.  Now, you can "trick" R into different views by using different library folders, but this requires some effort.  A few packages want to help with that, the renv package is a recent addition.  Otherwise, doing it "differently" is a solution and e.g. is a good approach.

Comment: Great, renv might actually be a better solution than I could imagine. if it works as I am thinking (like a docker container may be)